# IF THEN statement to search and return information from column of options

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I need a formula that says IF cell A1 = any of the content in any of the cells in column C, THEN cell B2 will be whatever content is in cell D of that same row as the matching C content.

in my situation, cell A1 is a specific cost code and column C is on a separate tab which is our entire list of cost codes.  Column D is also on that seperate tab and is the dollar value associated with the cost in columc C.  I want cell B2 to display the dollar value of the matching cost code.

Comment: Take a look at VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0):

Like Fixer1234 wrote in the comment you will be best off using the `VLOOKUP` formula. If you have a table like the one below you'll use in column B the formula `=VLOOKUP(A1,C:D,2,FALSE)`

```
cost  | Formula |  Cost   |Price
      | Here    | Table   |
=================================
Test  |         | One     | $1
---------------------------------
One   |         | Yeast   | $2
---------------------------------
Two   |         | Apple   | $3
---------------------------------
Three |         | Three   | $4
---------------------------------
      |         | Two     | $5
---------------------------------
      |         | Tryout  | $6
---------------------------------
      |         | Test    | $7
```